# Place for Anaconda on macOS

Tags: macos, python

There are several posts that are discussing relevant aspects of Anaconda installation on macOS [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/371888/restore-access-to-file-system-for-emacs-on-macos-catalina) and [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/373133/problems-using-anaconda-in-macos-catalina), and elsewhere. My question is more of a principled kind: what would be an appropriate place for installation?

Previously, the place was in `/Library/Frameworks/`. (BTW, this is where `R` still lives in `R.framework`.) More recently, this was moved to `opt` and now `opt` is moved to `HOME`. So, really, what should be the right place for developer frameworks such as `python` or `R`?

I do like to have a system-wide installation but then maintenance becomes painful with all the security issues.

Thanks!