# How to disable Documents folder protection?

Tags: finder, xcode, permission, catalina

I'm working on a C++ program in Xcode, which opens some files in the project folder, which is in `~/Documents/Xcode Projects`. Because it's in my Documents folder, every time I run the program, it asks for permissions to access my documents folder, and I have to click yes every time. I tried explicitly giving the program permission in the settings, and that works for a little bit, but after about 3 runs of the program it asks for permissions again. Can I just disable the document folder protection? How?

Comment: Easiest thing is to move Xcode Projects outside any of the protected folders. E.g. I store my Xcode stuff in ~/Developer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Restore Access to File System for Emacs on MacOS Catalina](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/371888/restore-access-to-file-system-for-emacs-on-macos-catalina)

Comment: @ankii The OP seems to have done this already.

Comment: It‘s not Xcode, it‘s the self-compiled program.

Comment: Ah missed that, @nohillside. Still, whatever interacts with files, C++, ruby, Python, bash should get the permission I guess.

Comment: C++ is compiled code. And with each new compilation the code /binary will be different. Don’t know whether the protection functionality can handle this (don‘t even know whether it would be a security risk if it tries, now that I start to think of it)

Answer (score 1):

The easy way is to turn off sandboxing for the app, in Xcode project settings under "capabilities". You might not want that though.

Otherwise you probably need a security-scoped bookmark to the directory. When you get access, create a bookmark from the directory URL using `bookmarkData(options:includingResourceValuesForKeys:relativeTo:)`. Make sure to use `.withSecurityScope` in the `options` argument. Save that to user defaults. Then when you want to use the directory,

- Read the bookmark from user defaults
- Initialize the URL using `init(resolvingBookmarkData:options:relativeTo:bookmarkDataIsStale:)` with options of `[.withSecurityScope, .withoutUI]`.
- Call `.startAccessingSecurityScopedResource()` before trying to use the URL.
- Call `.stopAccessingSecurityScopedResource()` when you're done with the URL.